# Is there any extra parameters or settings need to be done to get unix socket connection through poll fd in C, linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I have a Unix domain socket server. In my server application, I have created a thread. In this thread, I have created a unix server socket. Also, I have created a poll fd that checks for any activity on the socket. So, there can be two activities on the socket - first is the connection accept and once the connection is accepted, I need to monitor that connection. In my example, I am assuming there will be just 1 socket client. My problem is that when the client application tries to connect, I never get an event on the socket for the connection. But, my client application says connected. Here is my server program and a client program. What am I missing here? I am puzzled. Is there any extra settings/parameters to do.
I feel that the logic is correct though.

Server App

```
#define WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME "/tmp/websock" 
int createServerSocket(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_un saddr;
    char buf[128];
    int sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to create UN socket, errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(saddr.sun_path, WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, sizeof(saddr.sun_path));
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("failed to bind address %s errno=%d: %s\n",
                WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, errno, buf);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
    if (listen(sock, 2) != 0) {
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("listen failed for %s errno=%d: %s\n",
                WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, errno, buf);
        close(sock);
        perror("listen failed: ");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Created WebIntStat Server\n");
    return sock;
}

void Thread()
    {
      int websock;
      struct pollfd fds[2];  
      nfds_t numfds;

      websock = CreateServerSocket();

      if( websock == -1)
       {
          printf("Failed in creating socket");
          return;
       }

       // make it usable by everyone 
       memset(fds, 0, sizeof(fds)); 
       chmod(WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, 0777);
       numfds = 1; // presently monitor 1 fd 
        fds[0].fd = webSock;
        fds[0].events = POLLIN;
        fds[0].revents = 0;

        while(1)
         {
            // Want to run this and check the data every 1 second to do other stuffs
            int events = poll(fds, numfds, 1000);
            if( events > 0)
            {
                 // I get this print
                printf("Got some events");
               if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
                 { 
                      // I never get this one ------
                      printf("Got Connection Request..accept it");

                      //socket accept code.

                 }
            }

         }   

    }
```

The client side code

```
#define SOCKET_PATH  "/tmp/websock"
int main()

    {
        int sockfd;
        int len;
        struct sockaddr_un address;
        int result;
        char ch[5] = "Start";


        /* -AF_UNIX is a UNIX internal socket, created on the filesystem.
         * -SOCK_STREAM is a reliable, sequenced, connection-based two-way byte stream
         *  (INET equivalent is TCP) */

        sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


        /* -sun_family - specifies type (domain) of socket
         * -sun_path - socket path location (on filesystem) */
        address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(address.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH);
        len = sizeof(address);


        /* request connection from the server, connecting socket to server with specified address
         * 'len' is the length of the address */
        result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);


        /* exit with error if connection is not successful */
        if(result == -1) {
            perror("oops: client1");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Connected");
        /* otherwise write data to server and obtain response */
        write(sockfd, ch, 5);
        read(sockfd, &ch, 5);
        printf("char from server: %s\n", ch);
        close(sockfd);

        exit(0);
    }
```

This is all running in embedded application so I don't have much socket utility to check on my busy box.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it works fine for me (tested on Debian 9.1).

I suspect it's caused by the `printf()` with strings without a terminating `\n` char. By default `printf()` to stdout on a tty/pty is line buffered and you'll not see the result until the `\n` or the buffer is full. So first you can try adding `\n` to your printf strings.

Comment: regarding unix sock path mismatch, it's a copy-n-paste error in stack overflow. Sorry. Next, I have syslog rather than printf. Does \n matters in syslog also?

Comment: does `\n` fix your problem? Syslog should work fine with non `\n`-terminated messages.

Comment: it didn't fixed my problem.

Comment: could you `printf("%#x %#x\n", fds[0].revents, POLLIN)` in the `if (events > 0)` block?

Comment: All the time - 0 0x1

Comment: it's really weird. what OS/libc (and version) are you using?

Comment: you can aslo try `select()` before finding out what's the real problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156543/discussion-between-dexterous-stranger-and-pynexj).

Comment: uclibc - c library and os - embedded linux. SOme other threads in the application is doing the same thing but it is problem in my thread only.

Comment: then i'd suggest u post a [mcve] so others can help debug.

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with pynexj. Try add '\n'**

there are some error in your code ,the socket path file name should be the same in server and client,and domain sockets can only used in local communication(client and server should in one machine and OS).

Debug these kind of simple problem, I found your client can connect to server correctly,and server show it get some event.(as the server print "...accept itGot some event...") .

I run your code in ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it will easily compatible in most Linux distributions.If you found embedded system is difficult to debug, you can debug them in your X86_64 PC first without using arm compiler ,then transplant your code to arm.

maybe you put your client and server in different machine ,and client open an local exist file(but in fact there is not server listenning),

or maybe there are some problems in your server IO or threads.

serv.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <signal.h>
#include <poll.h>
#define WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME "/tmp/websock" 
int createServerSocket(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_un saddr;
    char buf[128];
    int sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to create UN socket, errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(saddr.sun_path, WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, sizeof(saddr.sun_path));
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("failed to bind address %s errno=%d: %s\n",
                WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, errno, buf);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
    if (listen(sock, 2) != 0) {
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("listen failed for %s errno=%d: %s\n",
                WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, errno, buf);
        close(sock);
        perror("listen failed: ");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Created WebIntStat Server\n");
    return sock;
}

void main()
{
    int websock;
    struct pollfd fds[2];  
    nfds_t numfds;

    websock = createServerSocket();

    if( websock == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed in creating socket");
        return;
    }

    // make it usable by everyone 
    memset(fds, 0, sizeof(fds)); 
    chmod(WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME, 0777);
    numfds = 1; // presently monitor 1 fd 
    fds[0].fd = websock;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[0].revents = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        // Want to run this and check the data every 1 second to do other stuffs
        int events = poll(fds, numfds, 1000);
        if( events > 0)
        {
            // I get this print
            printf("Got some events");
            if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
            { 
                // I never get this one ------
                printf("Got Connection Request..accept it");

                //socket accept code.

            }
        }

    }   

}
```

cli.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#define SOCKET_PATH  "/tmp/websock"
//#define WEBSOCK_PATH_NAME "/tmp/websock" 
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_un address;
    int result;
    char ch[5] = "Start";


    /* -AF_UNIX is a UNIX internal socket, created on the filesystem.
     * -SOCK_STREAM is a reliable, sequenced, connection-based two-way byte stream
     *  (INET equivalent is TCP) */

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


    /* -sun_family - specifies type (domain) of socket
     * -sun_path - socket path location (on filesystem) */
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(address.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH);
    len = sizeof(address);


    /* request connection from the server, connecting socket to server with specified address
     * 'len' is the length of the address */
    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);


    /* exit with error if connection is not successful */
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("oops: client1");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected");
    /* otherwise write data to server and obtain response */
    write(sockfd, ch, 5);
    read(sockfd, &ch, 5);
    printf("char from server: %s\n", ch);
    close(sockfd);

    exit(0);
}
```

you can compile them with following commands:

```
gcc serv.c -o serv
gcc cli.c -o cli
```

clean the socket file if it already in use:

```
rm -rf /tmp/websock
```

then run them:

```
./serv
./cli
```

server side output:

```
Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..ac
cept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..a
ccept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..
accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request.
.accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request
..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Reques
t..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Reque
st..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Requ
est..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Req
uest..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Re
quest..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection R
equest..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection 
Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection
 Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connectio
n Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connecti
on Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connect
ion Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connec
tion Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Conne
ction Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Conn
ection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Con
nection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Co
nnection Request..accept itGot some eventsGot Connection Request..accept itGot some events
```

Comment: Sorry, the unix domain socket path name was a problem while posting the problem.